# Flutter app crash when trying to upload picture from firebase bucket

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-storage

Basically I have the app in flutter using Xcode and iOS, in profile section I try to upload picture then the app crash and shutdown , iam trying to fix it since months, if someone can hellp

```
void _deletePicture(index) async {
if (widget.currentUser.imageUrl[index] != null) {
  try {
    StorageReference _ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .getReferenceFromUrl(widget.currentUser.imageUrl[index]);
    print(_ref.path);
    await _ref.delete();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
setState(() {
  widget.currentUser.imageUrl.removeAt(index);
});
var temp = [];
temp.add(widget.currentUser.imageUrl);
await Firestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .document("${widget.currentUser.id}")
    .setData({"Pictures": temp[0]}, merge: true);
```

}
}

the error in Xcode throwing

> Thread 1: Exception: “URL must be in the form of http[s]://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b//o/<path/to/object>[?token=signed_url_params]”

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: It looks like the URL you're passing is not valid. If you print `widget.currentUser.imageUrl[index]`, what does it show?

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for replying, what do you mean what does it show ? in debugger ?

Comment: I'm using by the way fire_storage 3.1.3 is that bug in this version ?